# unique function in uitable matlab

Tags: matlab, unique

I have program to display data in a uitable use unique function:

```
data_plat = load('Data_Plat.mat');
Database_All = data_plat.Database_All;
data2 = table2cell(Database_All(strcmpi(Database_All.Plat, final_output), ...
    {'Plat', 'Nama', 'Jurusan', 'Status'}));
data2 = [get(handles.uitable1, 'Data'); data2];
[~,idx]=unique(cell2mat(data2),'rows');
unique_data2 =  data2(idx,:);
set(handles.uitable1, 'Data', unique_data2);
```

final_output is a number computed by the program which always changes because the program is processing video.

when its starting, its doing normally, but when second data in(final_output), it get error message :

> ```
> Error using cat
> Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.   
> Error in cell2mat (line 78) m = cat(1,m{:});      
> Error in mpengujianbmpengujianbplay_Callback (line 222)
> T=cell2mat(data2);
> ```

when i run this code without unique funtion, its doing fine(no error message) but always replicate in table so i appending unique funtion to solve that, the question is what must i do, something wrong with my code(unique function) or add another function to solve my problem(replicate data in table)?

Comment: If `final_output` is a number, why are using it as the second argument to a string comparison function?

Comment: Try to use the debugger to understand the error message, i.e. look at the matrices you want to concatenate.

Comment: i dont want to concatenate matrices, this program is database,  i want data is added to the table without erasing (or replicating) what's already there, so i use unique function, first data in(final_output), succes read n show in table, but when second data in, its get error...

Comment: Please read the error message and see: [mcve]. The error has nothing to do with `unique` and everything to do with `data2`, which we can't address because we're not omniscient.

Comment: when i run this code without unique funtion, its doing fine(no error message) but always replicate in table so i appending unique funtion to solve that, the question is what must i do, something wrong with my code(unique function) or add another function to solve my problem(replicate data in table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i alrdy solve this problem, error because i convert to mat, thats why Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. so the code is

```
%% Database
data_plat = load('Data_PlatQ.mat');
Database_All = data_plat.Database_All;
data2 = table2cell(Database_All(strcmpi(Database_All.Plat, final_output), ...
    {'Plat', 'Nama', 'Jurusan', 'Status'}));
data2 = [get(handles.uitable1, 'Data'); data2];
    [~,idx]=unique(cell2table(data2),'rows');
    unique_data2 =  data2(idx,:);    
    set(handles.uitable1, 'Data', unique_data2);
```